# Two hands with seven fingers

Tags: riddle

Here is my first riddle on this site ; I hope it fits in the right spirit:

> I have two hands with seven fingers
> that should never touch the others.
>
> My first hand knows how to pull,
> apply a force, it's so helpful.
> Sometimes home, sometimes away,
> This hand is always blocking the way.
>
> My other hand can use hammers,
> Or knives, or blades, if it prefers.
> These two fingers are for handling,
> the other ones are for cutting.
>
> When one middle finger raises, above the others,
> ultimate offense! This is the point.
> But these fingers are all brothers,
> 'cause at the end, they are all joint.

Who am I?

It seemed a bit difficult, so some elements were added and the puzzle reworded a bit, that should put you on the right way ... or not?

Comment: Seven fingers on each hand, or seven fingers between them?

Comment: Seven fingers on each hand.

Comment: I'm desperately trying to fit in Wolverine or Doctor Octopus. Ain't working out.

Comment: Ehum..this-> http://exclaim.ca/images/up-bruce_almighty.jpg

Comment: I have fixed the quoteblock (see revision history for how that works, especially for line breaks) and the punctuation, it is not clear whether you intended a gap as a disguised hint or they are simply a practised error.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Line gaps are here just for the ease of reading, and to make the riddle look like a poem.

Comment: Also, the gap before the ! is just because I'm French, and the French rule is to leave a gap before punctuation signs like `!`, `?`, `:` and `;`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Can you be found in the average Frenchman's home?

Comment: @Nzall No. But people from North-America are more likely to find the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> an Ultimate frisbee game

I have two hands with seven fingers

> 2 teams, 7 players each

that should never touch the others.

> Theoretically it's a non-contact sport

My first hand knows how to pull,

> A pull is how a point is started (one team throwing to the other)

apply a force, it's so helpful.
Sometimes home, sometimes away,

> Force is the way you defend usually on one side to force the player to throw one way.  Home and away are how you decide which way as a team to force (home is the side with team benches).

This hand is always blocking the way.

> Team on defense is trying to block

My other hand can use hammers,
Or knives, or blades, if it prefers.

> Hammers and blades are are types of throws (not sure about knives)

These two fingers are for handling,
the other ones are for cutting.

> A general team line up is typically 2 (or 3) handlers or people that are usually throwing the discs.  The others are called cutters and are responsible for cutting, getting open and catching the disc (they usually try to get it back to the handlers if there is no easy way forward)

When one middle finger raises, above the others,
ultimate offense! This is the point.

> If one player jumps higher and catches the disc in the endzone it is a point)

But these fingers are all brothers,
'cause at the end, they are all joint.

> It's generally a very close knit community and teams will often do something together at the end, be it shake hands, spirit games (silly game at the end), etc.

Comment: Good catch ! That's the correct answer !

Comment: You can get a better explanation of the last sentence, though :)

Comment: @Ratbert Spirit circles? (I think thats what they were called) where the two teams stand in a circle alternating teams with arms on shoulders to discuss game, mvp or most spirited player.  Cant quite remember what was talked about.  Been a number of years since I played in a league that did this.  Where i am now its always spirit games

Comment: It's called a *huddle* :)

Comment: Rumor has it that a _joint_ was once passed among the fingers at a concluding meeting of the hands

Answer (score 18):

Who am I ?

> [Kikkerland Multi Function Hammer Tool](https://kikkerland.com/products/multi-function-hammer-tool-with-pouch)
>        
>   <sup>(Click within spoilers to permanently unhide them.)</sup> 
>  
>         
>  [image]

```
I have two hands with seven fingers
that should never touch each other.
```

> The tool has **two** ends,
>  from which a total of **seven** extremities swing.
>  
>  The “hands” and “finger(tip)s”
>  are mechanically prevented from touching.

```
My first hand knows how to pull,
apply a force, it's so helpful.
```

1. > nail puller / pliers / pincher

```
My other hand can use hammers,
```

2. > hammer head

```
Or knifes, or blades, if it prefers.
```

3. > knife
4. > saw blade / file / screwdriver
5. > screwdriver / reamer

```
Two fingers are for handling,
Other fingers are for cutting.
```

6. > handle / bottle opener
7. > scissors

Comment: Omg such a nice try ! However the answer is totaly different.

Comment: Not surprised that something more interesting is afoot, just couldn't resist posting such a coincidental match (and trippy picture)

Comment: I thought of something like this, but dismissed it as in that case the question would be hardly a riddle but more a straightforward description of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> an American Football match?

Two hands with 7 fingers

> An american Football match has 2 teams, each of which with 7 players in the main part of the match and 4 players at the sides.

Will attempt to add the rest if my answer is the right one.

Comment: It's not the answer I'm looking for, but you're very, very close !

Comment: Gtwebb has been faster, he has the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> A gamer

I have two hands with seven fingers
that should never touch the others.

> One hand on WASD and the other on the mouse

My first hand knows how to pull,
apply a force, it's so helpful.
Sometimes home, sometimes away,
This hand is always blocking the way.

> The left hand is generally used for mobility and can be used to go home, block the way, pull things, push things, etc

My other hand can use hammers,
Or knives, or blades, if it prefers.
These two fingers are for handling,
the other ones are for cutting.

> The right hand is the mouse and is often used for attacking with things like knives and such

When one middle finger raises, above the others,
ultimate offense! This is the point.
But these fingers are all brothers,
'cause at the end, they are all joint.

> I'm not sure about the first half of this, but maybe the gamer has special attacks mapped to q, e, or the number keys?
>  But in the end, they're all attached to the gamer

Comment: Interesting try, but that's not the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Gamers don't have seven fingers on each hand though.

Comment: @randal'thor 5 fingers for the WASD keys and surrounding, plus 2 for the mouse buttons is a way to say "two hands totalling seven fingers".